# jQuery validate — Require one specific selection which has a particular data attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to figure out how to validate a specific scenario with jQuery validate. The user must select at least one user from a group of users, but each user in the list has a `data` attribute representing a score, let's say 0-100; and let's say they must select at least 1 user with a score over 70. For example...

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="user_ids[]" id="user_ids_1" data-score="50">
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="user_ids[]" id="user_ids_2" data-score="80">
etc...
```

```
$("form#coolForm").validate({
  rules: {
    'user_ids[]': {
      required: true,
      minLength: 1,
    }
  }
});
```

This will require the selection of at least one user, but is there a way to require the selection of one user where `elem.data('score') >= 70` ?

Comment: Normally, when validating checkboxes, you only want to make sure one or more checkboxes from the group are ticked.  You normally don't exclude certain checkboxes from being chosen - otherwise, why would they be there?  This is an unusual and poor GUI design.  Why show the user any options they are not allowed to select in the first place?

Comment: @Sparky re-read the scenario before saying it's a poor GUI decision. They can select anyone they want, the requirement is that they have to choose at least one user with a score > X, after that there are no restrictions.

Comment: That makes no difference.  Your GUI should take that into account and not present the user with checkboxes that they are not allowed to select.  This is not a normal scenario, which is why the plugin can't handle it and you're having such difficulty accomplishing.

Comment: "checkboxes that they are not allowed to select"... but they are allowed to select them

Comment: *"... they are allowed to select them"* - if that were true, then you wouldn't need validation, and you wouldn't be posting this question.  Normally, a user can select ANY checkbox(s).  When you want them to select "at least one that is >70", along with options that are not >70, you are effectively presenting them with an overall scenario that they are not allowed to select.  It's very poor GUI.  ALL choices in the checkbox grouping should be >70 if that's what you want them to pick from.

Comment: Why not break it up in to two checkbox groups.  One group where everything is >70, and a second grouping of the rest?  Then you would not need to invent custom validation for such an arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got the answer

you need to add a method to the validator and get the score you want to compare, params being the number you want to compare to and return true or false (in this example if the HTML Element data-score is equal or higher than 50 it'll pass.

```
$.validator.addMethod("checkScore", function(value, element, params) {
        const score = $(element).data("score");
        console.log(params);
    console.log(score);
    return score >= params;
}, "This is your custom validation error message");
```

you can check the example here:

```js
$.validator.addMethod("checkScore", function(value, element, params) {
        const score = $(element).data("score");
        console.log(params);
    console.log(score);
    return score >= params;
}, "This is your custom validation error message");

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            "user_ids][]": {
                checkScore: 50
            },
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.insertBefore(element);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.3/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.3/additional-methods.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="user_ids][]" id="user_ids_1" data-score="40">
<br/>
<input type="text" name="textfield">
<br/>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks, i think we're on the right track, but there's still a couple issues i can't work out. The first checkbox in my list is getting passed to the `checkScore` method whether it's actually checked or not.

Comment: actually I may have a solution now, not sure if it's the "right" way, but it seems to be working. Will post an update later today.

Comment: Since its checking all the inputs from "user_ids][]" every checkbox will be validated, you'll need to maybe get the array before submitting the form, get the array of inputs and filter it to get the values you need?